# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Cucumber test package

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to set up a very simple Cucumber test environment using Eclipse. I am following a tutorial and created the project with required reference libraries:

[Referenced Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFRrw.png)

I have created the CucumberRunner.java file with the following content:

```
package cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
    features = "src/cucumber"
    )

public class CucumberRunner {

}
```

and also create a feature file and step definitions. If I run the from, the feature files, the tests run correctly. But, if I run from the CucumberRunner.java, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:80)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

I have installed the Cucumber Eclipse Plugin as per another answered question so I am at a total loss as to why this is happening. If I try to add JARs to include the missing libraries, I just seem to move the problem to a difference missing library.

I think it must be to do with the versions of libraries I am using but I am a complete novice at this and have no experience of how to problem solve this.

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem with some other class not being found. I also had the glue and runner classes in a package cucumber like you have. I tried renaming the cucumber package and it worked..

Comment: Share your maven/ant build file, Junit/TestNG/something_else test framework, testng.xml, if you have one and a class file. If your tutorial is free, share that link.

Comment: Renaming the cucumber package worked. I find this both amazing and incredibly annoying. Thanks to both Grasshopper and Sid for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sid's comment above, renaming the cucumber class fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to add *glue="cucumber.steps"*, to the CucumberOptions list.

Comment: Good first answer! When the path containing the step definitions is not in the class path it has to be added using the glue option.  If steps is a folder off of the classpath (E.g. claspath=src/main/java and steps are in src/main/java/steps) then I add glue = {"classpath:steps"}